# Typo3 7.2 Where to edit default templates + backend layouts?

Tags: typo3

Where do I edit default backend layouts that come with typo3 7.2 official introduction package? there is a table in the db that holds backend layouts but only those that I created, not the default ones. But where do I find the colPos layout for the default templates that already come with the installation? I only want to make slight modification in the html template and I'd like to make the changes editable from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Backend layouts are defined via `PageTS` below `mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts.<key>.` This is not a standard functionality, but a possibility provided by one of the integrated extensions.

The mapping of the `backend layout ids` to the `template files` is done in the actual `TypoScript` template at the path `page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject.<key>.value`.
For `backend layouts` created via the database, the key is the numeric id of the `backend layout record`.